# cannot open simultaneously 2 tabs within same web app on safari ipad/iphone using SignalR

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, ipad, signalr

The web app is powered with require.js, jquery, underscorejs, signalR. MVVM with knockoutjs. 
Working within one tab is fine. Trying to open a part of application in new tab, does not work. Looking in safari web inspector displays that different scripts / css are endless loading. If I switch back to first opened tab it still works fine and can be reloaded. If i close the first tab, the second is loaded then fine (without reloading, seems like it waits for something in the first tab).

Thank you for any help.

Edit: 
I found that the reason is SignalR - after disabling it the second tabs works well. This is strange, because the ipad limit is 5 concurrent connections, and signalR keeps one open. 
Any ideas ? SignalR is 1.1.2

Answer (score 0):

Found the reason:  IOS Safari is limited to one active connection per server, that causes second tab to wait until first is closed.

Using long pooling fixed the issue:

```
$.connection.hub.start({ transport: 'longPolling' });
```